# Need help using two data sources for maps

Tags: tableau-api

Today is my first day learning Tableau so forgive me if this is easy.  I created a map of the United States using one data set and now I want to create another map in another sheet of the world using a completely different data set.  None of the columns are the same. Every time I try to do something with it, I get the pop up that I need to create a relationship with the first data set.  There is no relationship so I don't know what to do.  This data set has nothing in common with the other.  All I want is to create this map as another sheet and then add them to the same story

Comment: Do you have any fields at all on the sheet for the world map that are from the United States data set? Tableau should only give you that popup if that is the case.

Comment: Make sure you are not accidentally using data from one dataset to plot on the maps from the other dataset.